# In TypeScript, why do I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"

Tags: typescript

I have a front-end TypeScript file named lib.ts as follows:

```
export function someFunc() {
    console.log("works");
}
```

In a second file, I import the library as follows:

```
import * as lib from "./lib";
```

This generates the following JavaScript:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const lib = require("./lib");
```

I then get the error:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined"
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: How do you run this file? `exports` is defined in nodejs

Comment: Through the browser